# URL showing wrong page after changing wordpress permalinks structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I am using [Book Your Travel](http://themeforest.net/item/book-your-travel-online-booking-wordpress-theme/5632266) wordpress theme, when I changed permalinks structure from default to postname, the URL automatically started showing wrong page (destinations) instead of going to homepage, here is my link I am talking about: http://gtu.innerdiv.com/

If I set permalinks structure to default, then it works fine (homepage get load)

I've checked the .htaccess file, it contains wordpress basic htaccess rules.

Comment: There is not enough information for anyone to be able to give you a reasonable answer to this problem.

Comment: @SamuelCook I've edited the question, is it clear enough now?

Comment: The homepage contains the slider, filter and few other things, but changing the permalinks structure shows me an inner page (destinations) on home URL i.e. http://gtu.innerdiv.com/

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried clearing your cache?